# count occurence of values individually and as a group in excel row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

o/p is the required column which is how many times D and P occured in a row either individually or as a group i.e if D and P occurs continuously, it is counted as 1. I am pretty sure there must be a formula for this somewhere only it is difficult to phrase the right words to search it. Hence this question here. Looking for a formula that does the job.

[image]

Comment: what is the logic to get 2 in second row?, there is no group (`D` immediate before `P`) I see `4D`s and `3P`s, so total should be `7`. Thanks

Comment: in second row, there are 2 instances where D and P occurred as group. hence o/p is 2. we are not counting individual D and P's, rather their occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the following a try, assuming it's either "U", "D" or "P":

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=BYROW(B1:L4,LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(a),"U",,1)),0)))
```

Above works for newest versions of Excel, for older CSE-required versions of Excel try:

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:L1<>"U",COLUMN(B1:L1)),IF(B1:L1<>"U",0,COLUMN(B1:L1)))>0))
```

Comment: I am getting a name error for this formula. What is 'a' here? Also, I am using excel 2016 and there does not seem to be a formula called 'LAMBDA' in the list.

Comment: Right, the answer uses functionality not available in Excel 2016. I'll add an option that is compatible to your version of Excel but requires CSE-entering. @user3471438

Comment: you mean array formula?

Comment: Yes @user3471438

Comment: Ok. It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

If `U` can be any text or character other than `P` or `D` then the following should work:

`=LEN(TEXTJOIN("",1,0,MMULT({1,1},--({"D";"P"}=B2:L2))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",1,0,MMULT({1,1},--({"D";"P"}=B2:L2))),"01",2))`

Or using Office 365 this spills the result:

```
=LET(t,BYROW(B2:L12,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN("",1,0,MAP(b,LAMBDA(m,--(OR(m={"D";"P"}))))))),
DROP(REDUCE(0,t,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,LEN(y)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(y,"01",2))))),1))
```

Both formulas convert the cells to 0 (FALSE) or 1 (TRUE) if the cell equals `P` or `D`. The results of one row are joined with a leading `0` and SUBSTITUTE looks for each occurrence of `01` in given string and replaces these 2 characters by 1. If we then compare it to the stringlength prior to the substitute, we have the answer to your question.